# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when checking for PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have this code

```
if (PreviousPage.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Form["username"] == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"] && Request.Form["password"] == ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"])
        {
            Session["username"] = Request.Form["username"];
            using (var context = new mallEntities())
            {
                var countProducts = (from p in context.Products
                                     select p).Count();

                var countStores = (from p in context.Stores
                                   select p).Count();

                var countCategories = (from p in context.Categories
                                       select p).Count();

                Label3.Text = countProducts.ToString();
                Label2.Text = countStores.ToString();
                Label1.Text = countCategories.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?invaild=true");
        }
    } else if(Session["username"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?session=false");
    }
```

and I got this error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

at `PreviousPage.IsPostBack`

Why?

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting? Where (what line) is it failing? Please provide some more information, as just the error you're getting doesn't really tell us anything (other than something isn't instantiated yet). Is this a post to a new page? If so, what method are you getting to this page (through a link, Server.Transfer, Response.Redirect, etc).

Comment: question, why not Page.IsPostBack? ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `PreviousPage.IsPosback` so I'll guess this is a mistake. You should use `Page.IsPostback`

In case you indeed want to use `PreviousPage` (I would be stumped) take into account that it can be null if you access the page direclty.

> > When you use the Transfer method or cross-page posting to transfer processing from one ASP.NET page to another, the originating page contains request information that might be required for the destination page. You use the PreviousPage property to access that information
> >
> > **The PreviousPage property is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) when the user requests that page directly from the server.**

Comment: I'm trying to submit to another page, so why PreviousPage should be null! and I want to check if form on the Previous Page is submitted to handle data processing

Comment: Please test `Page.IsPostback`, it should be true.